# String processing Based on methods

Tags: javascript, html, methods

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset ="utf-8"/>
    <title> Exercise 1</title>
    <style>
      body  {
        background-image: url("http://www.millionglitters.com/background/thumb/nice/nice-background-pattern-176.gif");  
      }

      label { display : inline-block;
        width :140px;
        text-align:left;
        padding-top:10px;
      }
    </style>
    <script>
      function con(){
        var str1=document.getElementById("str1").value;
        var str2=document.getElementById("str2").value;
        var res = str1.concat(" "+str2);
        alert(res);
      }
      function sub(){
        var str1=document.getElementById("str1").value;
        var str2=document.getElementById("str2").value;
        var res1 = str1.substr(1,4);
        var res2 = str2.substr(1,4);
        alert(res1+" "+res2);
      }
      function last(){
        var str1=document.getElementById("str1").value;
        var str2=document.getElementById("str2").value;
        var str3=document.getElementById("str3").value;
        var res = str1.concat(" "+str2);
        var n=res.lastIndexOf(str3);
        alert(n);
      }
      function lower(){
        var str1=document.getElementById("str1").value;
        var str2=document.getElementById("str2").value;
        var res = str1.concat(" "+str2);
        var res2=res.toLowerCase();
        alert(res2);
      }
      function upper(){
        var str1=document.getElementById("str1").value;
        var str2=document.getElementById("str2").value;
        var res = str1.concat(" "+str2);
        var res2=res.toUpperCase();
        alert(res2);
      }
      function match(){
        var str1=document.getElementById("str1").value;
        var str2=document.getElementById("str2").value;
        var str4=document.getElementById("str4").value;
        var res = str1.concat(" "+str2);
        var res2=res.match(str4);
        alert(res2);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body> 
    <h1>String processing Based on methods</h1>
    <p><b>concat()</b>
      used to join two or more strings.This method does not change 
      the existing strings, but returns a new string containing the text 
      of the joined strings.</p>
    <p><b>substr()</b>
      extracts parts of a string, beginning at the character at the 
      specified position, and returns the specified number of characters.</p> 
    <p><b>lastIndexOf()</b>
      method returns the position of the last occurrence of a specified 
      value in a string. This method is case sensitive</p>
    <p><b>toLowerCase()</b>
      method converts a string to lowercase letters.</p>
    <p><b>toUpperCase()</b>
      method converts a string to uppercase letters.</p>
    <p><b>match()</b>
      searches a string for a match against a regular expression, and returns
      the matches, as an Array object.</p>
    <form>
      <fieldset>
        <legend><i>Input String</i></legend>
        <label for ="str1">Input first Sentence</label>
        <input type="text" id="str1" size="25" required><br />
        <label for ="str2">Input second Sentence</label>
        <input type="text" id="str2" size="25" required><br />

        <p><b>The input field below is use for CERTAIN method only</b></p>

        <label for ="str3">Choose from sentence a last word</label>
        <input type="text" id="str3" size="25" required 
               placeholder="for lastIndexOf()"><br />
        <label for ="str4">Choose a regular expression</label>
        <input type="text" id="str4" size="25" required
               placeholder="for match()"><br />
        <label for ="str5">A word to replace/ Where</label>
        <input type="text" id="str5" size="25" required 
               placeholder="Replace Word, replace()">
        <input type="text" id="str6" size="25" required 
               placeholder="What word to replace, replace()"><br /><br />
        <button type="button" onclick="con()">concat()</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="sub()">substr()</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="last()">lastIndexOf()</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="lower()">toLowerCase()</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="upper()">toUpperCase()</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="match()">match()</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="replace()">replace()</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="split()">split()</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="charCodeAt()">charCodeAt()</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="slice()">slice()</button>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm planning to write the codes of all JavaScript method as above. It is a good behavior of writing the codes like this?. I'm thinking why don't i put all method in one function. Is that possible?
Just asking...and I'm a beginner. Thanks for helping

Comment: All methods in what function? Can you explain with an example? Usually you should let a function/method perform a single task its supposed to and not merge multiple methods into one; it complicates code

Comment: for example if i want to use splice() and replace(), i'll create the function only for splice() and other function for replace:                                  function splice(){     } function replace(){    } then i used button to access the function. So it's better use one method in one function? @TheUknown

Comment: Yes, thats correct. You can call also call those functions from your other main function example - `function processSomething(){ //call splice(); and replace(); here to do something}`

Comment: ok..thanks @TheUknown